# What is the default cmdline.txt for Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, cmdline.txt

I need to know the default contents of the `cmdline.txt` file for a Raspberry Pi 4. I was following an old tutorial about setting up a gps module. The tutorial had me change the contents `cmdline.txt`. Only after I made the change and the RPi4 failed to boot did I realize the tutorial was for an older model Pi. There is an answer for this question here [What is the default cmdline.txt?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27802/what-is-the-default-cmdline-txt), however it is also for an older model Pi.

Comment: I vaguely remember the last time I used cmdline.txt was when some 4 years ago, setting up wheezy or jessie. From stretch on I never need to use cmdline.txt again. I have been playing with GSP without using cmdline.txt.  You might like to check out how set up GPS modules. (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/how-can-rpi-change-neo-6m-gps-update-rates
(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113057/how-can-rpi-listen-to-a-gps-module
(3) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/how-can-rpi-connect-a-gps-module。 Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On my Pi 4, it's:

> console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=XXXXXXXX-02
> rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet
> splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles

Your PARTUUID will not be the same as mine (which is why I X'd it out).  Instead, use:

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

Note the PARTUUID for the root partition (ext4) and that's the value you need to use.

Comment: Your `PARTUUID` ends with `-02`, but I'm assuming that's gonna be the partition where root is. For me that's `-03`. I initially did the mistake of using `lsblk -o UUID,NAME`, and took me a while to realize this was supposed to be `PARTUUID` and not only `UUID`.